# Calculating time from timesheet in while statement PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a heck of a time with this.  I have been looking and I see different things I could use like [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html), [date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), [SUM](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp), Javascript Math, etc.  Problem is I dont know which one to use or which one I would use in my case.  The more I read different threads and "solutions" the more I get confused on how to apply this to my needs.

I have a simple timesheet table in my database called "timesheet" in it I have the columns entry_id (AI), user_id, firstname, lastname, punch (datetime) and comment (in/out). I have done a simple query in PHP to bring in the users timesheet into an HTML table like below.
[image: timesheet table HTML]

In my PHP query I am running a WHILE statement to loop through the records.  Because I am using a loop I have no idea how I can/would calculate the time to give an overall total of hours worked for that time period.

Here is my query:

```
$timesheet = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(punch, '%Y/%m/%d') AS punch_date, DATE_FORMAT(punch, '%H:%i:%s') AS punch_time, comment
                    FROM timesheet WHERE user_id = '$employee' AND punch BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'") or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connect));

if(mysqli_num_rows($timesheet)>0){
    $output = '<table class="table table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Date</th>
                      <th>Time</th>
                      <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($timesheet, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $date = $row['punch_date'];
        $time = $row['punch_time'];
        $status = $row['comment'];

        $output .= '<tr>
                      <td>' . $date . '</td>
                      <td ';
        if($status === 'In'){ 
            $output .= 'class="in-time"'; 
        } elseif($status === 'Out') {
            $output .= 'class="out-time"';
        }

        $output .= '>' . $time . '</td>
                      <td>' . $status . '</td>
                    </tr>';

    } //end while

    $output .= '</tbody>
                </table>';


    echo $output;

} //end if mysqli_num_rows
```

Is it even possible to calculate the time in a loop?  If so would you mind giving an example and of not could you point me on the direction of where/what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Each time entry has either In or Out as a status, so I need to get the difference of each set of In and Out, then add that together to get the total number of time worked for that time period.  Ultimately this is what I need to accomplish (see Total in red at bottom of table)
[image: Hopeful outcome]

An here is a snapshot of the database table "timesheet"
[image: database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the while() we have to decide if we will use all rows to calculate the total time or not.

Because there is a catch here. What if a user has logged in but hasn't logged out yet?

In this case we will not use the last logged in time in our total. So:

```
$iterations = mysqli_num_rows($timesheet) % 2 == 0 ? mysqli_num_rows($timesheet) : mysqli_num_rows($timesheet) - 1;
```

Inside your while loop, convert punch_time to seconds.

```
while() {

...

$parts = explode(':', $row['punch_time']);

$seconds = (int) $parts[0] * 3600 + (int) $parts[1] * 60 + (int) $parts[2];

if($status === 'In'){ 

   $output .= 'class="in-time"'; 

   $total -= $iterations ? $seconds : 0; // Subtract from total when in and there is out coming

} else if($status === 'Out') {

   $output .= 'class="out-time"';

   $total += $seconds; // Add  to total when out
}

...

$iterations--;

}
```

After the loop you can transform seconds to the format you want by using

```
$hours = floor($total / 3600);

$minutes = floor(($total / 60) % 60);

$seconds = $total % 60;

echo "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
```

Comment: Wow, +1 for the creativetity, thank you!  I have a quick question though - using the image above as a reference when I echo out $total (still in seconds) I get 202851 seconds, when that converts to hours it comes out to 56.3475 hours.  So somewhere the conversion is wrong.  In the image if I do the math by hand it roughly comes out to overall total of 15 minutes worked, which would convert to .25 hours.  Where would that issue be?

Comment: You are absolutely right! The calculation was wrong. I think this will do the trick. It's 56:16:51 in your case.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of your help, I see that your code is adding the total number of time entries and giving that result as the total.  I have updated the question to hopefully be a little more clear of my issue.  Hopefully this will shed some light on the desired outcome, you have been very helpful so far.  Each entry has a status of either In or Out, what I need to do is find the difference in time between each set of In and Out entries, then I will be adding that together to get the total time worked during that period in hours.

Comment: Now i understand what you're trying to achieve. Check updated answer

Comment: Thanks tliokos, something still is not quite right and I am guessing it is in the math somewhere?  Referring to the table above in the image the total should come out to about 0.25083 but when I implement your code the total says Total: 0:53:55 (as in 53 minutes and 55 seconds), I think it should equal 00:15:03 if my math is correct.

Comment: I replicated your database and the code seems to work fine. My result is 00:14:47. By the way in the second image you posted the first interval is not 00:14:50 but 00:14:34. Are there any other rows in your database that are not visible in the first image? Is the order of your result as the one depicted is your first image?

Comment: Thanks, the snapshots above were from the page that is outputting the results in an HTML table, I did however just update the question to include a snapshot of the database.  Also, if it helps I added the full file to a pastebin for you to preview, maybe I have something wrong I am missing.  Line 88 is where the query starts and your customizations have been added around line 112.  Hope this helps, thanks again for your help.. Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/YTG0Jd1w

Comment: OK i see. You've placed some code in the wrong place. Check [here](http://pastebin.com/E8jiDv2u)

Comment: Thanks again for all the help, I see what I did wrong and it seems to be working now, how easy would this be to convert the time to hours so it would read 0.25083 hours?

Comment: Very easy. Just use `echo number_format($total/3600, 5);` where 5 is the number of decimals you want.